# Разбор строки на части

Tags: python, строки, парсер

Здравствуйте, посылаю в питон строку вида

```
&5:420:0:03713031464@
```

Которую надо разобрать на следующие части

```
(start byte) (data length) : (type of message) (priority) (data1) : (data2): (data3) (CRC) (end byte)
```

При этом длина данных(data length), собственно сами данные ((data1) : (data2): (data3)) и (CRC) имеют динамическую длину.

Собственно вопрос, как правильно разобрать такую строку(данные всегда приходят в виде x:x:x)? Пытался составить регулярное выражение, ничего не вышло. Спасибо.

Comment: обновите ваш вопрос и явно укажите желаемый результат для приведённого ввода (чему равен "start byte", "data length", "type of message", priority, data1, data2, data3, CRC, "end byte").

Answer (score 1):

```
print "&5:420:0:03713031464@".split(":")
```

На выходе будет ['&5', '420', '0', '03713031464@'] - почти то что вам нужно. Убираете первый символ первого элемента списка и последний последнего и вот результат.

Comment: К сожалению не почти. Длина CRC может быть как 6 так и 12 символов. То же можно сказать и о последней "ячейке" с данными. Например:
&5:42100:100:10037130314568464@

Comment: @DWilde и что? Вы получите строку разделенную на поля в любом случае.

Comment: `"&5:420:0:03713031464@"[1:-1].split(":")`

Answer (score 0):

а разбить строку в массив, используя в качестве разделителя двоеточие:

```
//data - приходящая строка

arr = data.split(':')
print('\n'.join(arr))
```

Проблема может быть решена изменением транспорта данных извне. Из всего вышеописаного выходит что контрольная сумма переведена в десятичные числа. Попробуйте, если это возможно, изменить транспорт данных. Если нет - то приведите это к шеснадцатитричному виду.

Comment: Разделителей в сообщении только 3, больше не предусмотрено.

Comment: Ну тогда уточните, чего именно вы хотите от этих данных получить?

Comment: По факту это формат сообщения, формируемый микроконтроллером. В питоне данные нужны для проверки целостности сообщения, а также инициализации GUI для управления системой.